# How to launch console application using CreateProcess with Minimized main window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console-application

I have a native c++ windows application that is launching two child processes using the following code -

```
if (!CreateProcess(NULL, // No module name (use command line)
    cmdLine, // szCmdline, // Command line
    NULL, // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL, // Thread handle not inheritable
    false, // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE | NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS // Process Create Flags
    NULL, // Use parent's environment block
    NULL, // workingDir, // Use parent's starting directory
    &si, // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi) // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
```

with all parameters in STARTUPINFO block 0.  This code works fine in launching the processes.  However, I need to be able to launch the windows c++ console applications with their windows minimized.

If I add CREATE_NO_WINDOW to the Process Create Flags, I can launch the processes without any windows.  This will be unacceptable.

In my research, there does not appear to be a way force a console application to open in a minimized mode.  Is this correct?

Yes, I know that I could minimize the child application windows from within their own process, however, the other programmers on the team prefer not to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to specify in the [STARTUPINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331%28VS.85%29.aspx) structure that you want your console window to be initially minimized:

```
ZeroMemory(&si);
si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = SW_MINIMIZE;
```

Comment: That only works on native Windows apps, not console mode apps.

Comment: @Hans, really? The documentation has a special case for "GUI processes", so what's the general case if console apps are not supported? :)

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  The value is passed to WinMain, nCmdShow argument.  Console mode apps don't have a WinMain.  Lots of GUI apps ignore it as well.

Comment: Actually, it worked on both a native console app and a Qt Windows app.  Thanks.

Comment: @Hans, the special case in the doc is: `For GUI processes, the first time ShowWindow is called, its nCmdShow parameter is ignored.` So I don't think they have a choice (unless they never call `ShowWindow()`). Nothing is said about the value being passed to `WinMain()`, it's only supposed to be used when `ShowWindow()` is called with `SW_SHOWDEFAULT`.

Comment: A console mode app may not have a WinMain() entry point, but the console itself dies, as it is a GUI app.  Lauching a console mode app starts a new console process. The CreateProcess() STARTUPINFO settings will apply to the console GUI window.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I think some apps can't be minimized upon launching using `CreateProcess` like (http://tftpd32.jounin.net/) . It tried to minimize that one but it can't be hidden.