# How to start cmd.exe using CreateProcess() without exiting cmd.exe immediately?

Tags: winapi, cmd, createprocess

I want to execute Windows' `cmd.exe` via `CreateProcess()` from my own command-line program. I redirect its input/output to another program I have written, which needs to have access to `cmd.exe`. But `cmd.exe` terminates immediately. I want to run `cmd.exe` until it receives `"exit"` from the other program communicating with it via the redirected stdin/stdout. I have tried no parameter, and the parameters `/C` and `/K`.

Here is my code:

```
ZeroMemory( &StartupInfo, sizeof(StartupInfo) );
StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(StartupInfo);
ZeroMemory( &ProcessInformation, sizeof(ProcessInformation) );
StartupInfo.hStdOutput = &cmd_stdout;
StartupInfo.hStdInput = &cmd_stdin;
StartupInfo.hStdError = &cmd_stderr;
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380575/how-to-launch-console-application-using-createprocess-with-minimized-main-window
StartupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
StartupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE;//SW_SHOWNORMAL also tried;
pprogstr = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe"; //gets substituted by GetSystemDirectory...
pargstr = '\0';//"/K";
LastError = 0;
OK = CreateProcess (
        pprogstr,           // pointer to name of executable module
        pargstr,            // pointer to command line string: full progname + parameters
        NULL,       // pointer to process security attributes
        NULL,       // pointer to thread security attributes
        TRUE,              // handle inheritance flag
        NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,// | DETACHED_PROCESS,   // creation flags
        NULL,       // pointer to new environment block
        NULL,       // pointer to current directory name
        &StartupInfo,      // pointer to STARTUPINFO
        &ProcessInformation        // pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION
);
LastError = GetLastError();
pidProcess = ProcessInformation.hProcess;
```

What do I have to change so `cmd.exe` does not terminate immediately?

---

Now I have written an executable sample program:

```
    /* a Win32 test program starting cmd.exe via CreateProcess */

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define logwrite dat = fopen ("cmdtest.log", "at"); fprintf
#define logend; fclose (dat);


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    STARTUPINFO StartupInfo; // pointer to STARTUPINFO
    PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInformation; // pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION
    char *pargstr, *pargstr2, *pprogstr;
    DWORD LastError, WaitResult, exit_code;
    FILE *dat;
    BOOL OK;

    ZeroMemory( &StartupInfo, sizeof(StartupInfo) );
    StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(StartupInfo);
    ZeroMemory( &ProcessInformation, sizeof(ProcessInformation) );
    //StartupInfo.hStdOutput = cmd_stdout;
    //StartupInfo.hStdInput = cmd_stdin;
    //StartupInfo.hStdError = cmd_stderr;
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380575/how-to-launch-console-application-using-createprocess-with-minimized-main-window
    StartupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    StartupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE;//SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    //please adapt the string
    pprogstr = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe";
    pargstr = "/K"; //"\0";
    logwrite (dat, "\n"); logend;
    logwrite (dat, "Trying CreateProcess pprogstr: %s; pargstr: %s;\n", pprogstr, pargstr); logend;
    LastError = 0;
    OK = CreateProcess (
            pprogstr,           // pointer to name of executable module
            pargstr,            // pointer to command line string: full progname + parameters
            NULL,       // pointer to process security attributes
            NULL,       // pointer to thread security attributes
            TRUE,              // handle inheritance flag
            NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,//0,//DETACHED_PROCESS | NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,   // creation flags
            NULL,       // pointer to new environment block
            NULL,       // pointer to current directory name
            &StartupInfo,      // pointer to STARTUPINFO
            &ProcessInformation        // pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION
    );
    LastError = GetLastError();
    logwrite (dat, "CreateProcess cmd.exe returns OK %i Processhandle %i LastError %i \n", OK, ProcessInformation.hProcess, LastError); logend;

    GetExitCodeProcess(ProcessInformation.hProcess, &exit_code);
    if (exit_code == STILL_ACTIVE) {
      logwrite (dat, "After 0 seconds, cmd.exe process is still active\n"); logend;
    }
    else {
      logwrite (dat, "After 0 seconds, cmd.exe process is no more active\n"); logend;
    }

    Sleep (2000);
    if (exit_code == STILL_ACTIVE) {
      logwrite (dat, "After 2 seconds, cmd.exe process is still active\n"); logend;
    }
    else {
      logwrite (dat, "After 2 seconds, cmd.exe process is no more active\n"); logend;
    }

    Sleep (8000);

    WaitResult = WaitForSingleObject (ProcessInformation.hProcess, INFINITE);
    LastError = GetLastError();
    if (WaitResult == WAIT_FAILED)
    {
       logwrite (dat, "WaitForSingleObject error: return code = %u Processhandle %i LastError %i\n", WaitResult, ProcessInformation.hProcess, LastError); logend;
    }
    else
    {
       logwrite (dat, "cmd.exe complete.\n"); logend;
    }
}
```

The log file shows:

```
Trying CreateProcess pprogstr: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe; pargstr: /K;
CreateProcess cmd.exe returns OK 1 Processhandle 252 LastError 183 
After 0 seconds, cmd.exe process is still active
After 2 seconds, cmd.exe process is still active
cmd.exe complete.
```

This is a strange behaviour:

- GetExitCodeProcess returns STILL_ACTIVE
- the Task Manager detail view shows no cmd.exe while pausing the program with Sleep
- WaitForSingleObject immediately exits cmd.exe.

The behaviour I want is that cmd.exe still runs and does not terminate (so my program should "hang").

Comment: `&cmd_stdout` and next - this is what ? `&` i mean. not pass any command line to cmd at all

Comment: You should enclose the whole command line (except \c or \k) with quotes.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT - this is need only in case when `lpApplicationName == 0`. and `CreateProcess*` need to parse command line. however problem here not in this anyway

Comment: You need to drop the `&` from `&cmd_stdout`, `&cmd_stdin`, and `&cmd_stderr`. `STARTUPINFO` expects `HANDLE`s assigned as-is by value, not by pointer.

Comment: How do you know cmd.exe is terminated? What does `CreateProcess` return?

Comment: @Anders, I have got a log file: "CreateProcess cmd.exe returns OK 1 pidProcess 288", that means cmd.exe has been started correctly. Then I do some minor stuff and the main thread waits by using the call "WaitResult = WaitForSingleObject (pidProcess, INFINITE);" This call terminates immediately (it should pause here, while another thread in my program still runs) without error. And I do not see cmd.exe in the "Detail" view of Task Manager.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, yes you're right. STARTUPINFO requires no pointers in this case. Correcting this did not change the behaviour, although you are right of course.

Comment: @MartinV "*the main thread waits by using the call `WaitResult = WaitForSingleObject (pidProcess, INFINITE);`*" - you can't wait on a process **ID**, you need to wait on a process **HANDLE** instead. `CreateProcess()` gives you both in the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` struct.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: Yes, the variable pidProcess holds the handle: `pidProcess = ProcessInformation.hProcess;` The non-perfect naming of my variable relates to the fact that my program is ported.

Comment: I have added now an executable sample code (see above, second code sample) where the program should start cmd.exe without leaving immediately, but I do not manage to omit an immediate exit. Both parameter "/K" and no parameter does not work. The sample program writes a log file "cmdtest.log".

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I solved the problem. cwCreationFlags CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE has to be added. The rest of the sample code is OK. Important is executing the full path name of CMD.EXE and the parameter /K.